# Route [review] not defined. LARAVEL Не работает редирект

Tags: php, laravel

Указываю имя в web.php

```
Route::get('/review', 'MainController@review')->name('review');
```

После отправки формы, я хочу перенаправлять на страницу review. В MainController пишу:

```
return redirect()->route('review');
```

Comment: смотрите через route:list есть ли маршрут. Так же его не будет если перед ним у вас есть такой маршрут:  Route::get('/{id}'....) или что-то похожее. Так как /review будет таким же паттерном как и /{id} чтобы это обойти надо определить маршрут /review перед /{id}

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте какие роуты зарегистрированы

```
php artisan route:list
```

и удостоверьтесь что есть роут с именем 'review'